# Add new row to database if it doesn't exist

Tags: sql

How can I only add a new user if it doesn't already exist?

Here is how I'm currently inserting a new user into the database

```
assert(typeof details.username === 'string');
db.execute("INSERT INTO user (??) VALUES (?)",
    [
        ['username'],
        [details.username]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just alter your column set `UNIQUE` attribute.

Well, it sounds like you only have one column in your table.

So, if you want a value to be inserted one your column must be set as `UNIQUE`.
See : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: please ad some explanation and depth to your answer

Comment: aded some explanations

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of options, one with pure SQL and not requiring any transactional checking as its an atomic statement:

```
INSERT INTO USER
select ? as username where not exists (select 1 from user where username = ?)
```